# Crystal Reports RecordSelectionFormula is always empty string

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

This is really grasping at straws, I apologize.

We've got some legacy VB.Net code that has stopped working now in VS 2015.

```
myReportClass.RecordSelectionFormula = "{report.IdField} = 13"
```

Now, after the assignment,  RecordSelectionFormula is still an empty string and when the report runs, it no longer filters by that value.

I *believe* the report files were created in CR 2010. I've referenced a NuGet package in order to get things working in VS2015.

Has anyone else seen this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after posting this I eventually wandered onto the SAP website and found [a reference to this KBA](http://search.sap.com/ui/notes?id=0001204895&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031323034383935&ssocompatible)

Essentially, you have to comment out two lines of generated code in the ReportViewer form designer.  After doing this, the intellisense still reports that the value of the property is empty string, but the report does filter properly.